# Is there an option similar to Simtest to test the behavior of mobile devices in different countries?

Tags: mobile, internationalization

Is there an option similar to Simtest to test the behavior of mobile devices in different countries?

I have seem 3gproxy but I would like to know if there are another options

Comment: We're also using 3gproxy.com, they're more stable than simtest, and introduced a chrome extension, which simtest still doesn't have

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what exactly you are trying to check.

If you are wondering how the app would behave in that specific territory and/or specific mobile service operator, then you have two other options:

**- Crowdtesting;**

You can basically hire remote testers from a specific country which will have specific mobile service providers SIM cards. it will be quite cheap if you want to do for example one test case, or short exploratory testing session.

For example:

```
http://www.utest.com/
https://www.testcloud.io/
http://www.testbirds.com/
https://crowdsourcedtesting.com/
https://www.pay4bugs.com/
http://www.mob4hire.com/
https://mycrowd.com/
https://test.io/
https://usabilityhub.com/
https://globalapptesting.com/
https://www.bugfinders.com/
http://www.usertesting.com/
http://whatusersdo.com/
http://trymyui.com/
```

**- Mobile Device Labs;**

So, there are many MDL services that allow you to use mobile devices which are in Poland, Germany, USA, Japan, China or so. Apart from a specific location from Play Store and Internet providers perspective, some of them allows you to use local SIM cards that are already configured in devices.

For example:

```
TestDroid
TestObject (Sauce labs)
Perfecto Mobile
NativeTap
Kobiton
Amazon AWS Device farm
Google FireBase
Xamarin Test Cloud
Experitest
Samsung Developers Lab
pCloudy
BrowserStack
```